# Using Trace Flag 2453 to Improve Table Variable Performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-administration

We have enabled trace flag 2453 (table variable performance) in SQL Server 2016 and it fixed the performance issues.

Is there any disadvantage to enabling this trace flag at the SQL Server level?

Please let me know your thoughts on this.

Answer (score 0):

First you should specify what this flag does:

> you can turn on trace flag 2453 to allow a table variable to trigger
>   recompile when enough number of rows are changed. This may allow the
>   query optimizer to choose a more efficient plan.

[FIX: Poor performance when you use table variables in SQL Server 2012 or SQL Server 2014](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2952444/fix-poor-performance-when-you-use-table-variables-in-sql-server-2012-o)

Now you can figure it out by yourself, what is a possible drawback.

If on your server many queries use table variables, this is OLTP system and you have too many recompilations, this TF can make it worse.

The same thing you could find here: [Using Trace Flag 2453 to Improve Table Variable Performance](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/02/using-trace-flag-2453-improve-table-variable-performance/)

> Should you always use trace flag 2453 or OPTION (RECOMPILE) if you are
>   using table variables? Maybe. But I’m leaning towards “it depends”.
>   Microsoft says the “**trace flag must be used with caution because it
>   can increase number of query recompiles which could cost more than
>   savings from better query optimization”**.

Answer (score 0):

A long time ago I remember my developers used to work with table variables instead of temporary tables because table variables were stored in memory vs temporary tables in tempdb where memory should be faster.  Even that this was true, at that time table variables didn't have statistics what caused performance issues where the tables stored more than 1 row. 
Not sure if this have changed but may be worth to take a look and see if can be better the usage of temp tables against variables and get rid of the trace flags, even that supported, I would prefer to not use them at all.